# How do I generate an ordered lists of the executed tasks when bitbaking a package?

Tags: yocto

I know that I can list the possible tasks with:

```
bitbake package -c listtasks
```

But this list also includes tasks that need to be called explicitly (like do_devshell or do_clean), and I wish to watch what is called when running:

```
bitbake package
```

Looking through the output obtained with 'bitbake -e package' also didn't provide much information I was able to parse.

Given that the order of tasks has to be explicitly defined with 'before' and 'after' when adding a task, I would expect it to be stored in some form.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The order in which all tasks executes are generally stored in

`poky/<build_directory>/tmp/work/<machine_toolchain>/<package_name>/<package_version>/temp/log.task_order`

For example
If you build python v2.7.12 utility, using 
`bitbake python` then the detailed task order will be available at

`poky/build/tmp/work/<machine_toolchain>/python/2.7.12-r1/temp/log.task_order`

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the 'temp' folder quite a lot, and still I never thought to look there.

Answer (score 4):

Another place to look is the cooker log file found here:
build_directory/tmp/log/cooker/machine_toolchain

It has a .log extension: (eg. 20190205192546.log) 
and shows the exact order of execution of tasks (all the do_... in the order that they are invoked).